# MySQL query issue for multiple condition check and update

Tags: mysql

Can we write query which can update single record based on successful achievement of 3 records field.

E.g

**first table: table1**

**first table fields**

id INT

name varchar

status enum('full', 'half') default Null

**Second table: table2**

**Second table fields**

id INT

table1_id int - foreign key

qty1 int

qty2 int

============

## table1

1

test

NULL

## table2

id - > 1

table1_id -> 1

qty1 -> 1

qty2 - > 2

---

id - > 2

table1_id -> 1

qty1 -> 2

qty2 - > 2

===============

One     To   Manny      Relationship

table 1 --> table 2

=======================

condition to update status field (of table1) to 'Full' is, 
For all records for table1_id in table2 , have Qty1 == qty2 (for all records of table1_id) and qty2 !=0

else rest to 'Half'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aggregate `Table2`, taking the `SUM()` of the boolean expression for which you wish to test each record, the result will be the number of matching records (because `TRUE` is converted to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`).  Therefore, one merely need check that the number of matching records is equal to the total number of records:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET status = (
  SELECT IF(SUM(Qty1=Qty2 AND Qty2!=0) = COUNT(*), 'full', 'half')
  FROM   Table2
  WHERE  table1_id = Table1.id
)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19fe8/1/0).